# How to add regularisation (L1/L2) to TensorFlow's Adam optimiser?

Tags: tensorflow, regularized

I am currently going through [Google's Machine Learning Crash Course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/training-neural-networks/programming-exercise) and I am experimenting with the DNNClassifier estimator for a binary classification problem. I am trying add regularisation (L1/L2) to Adam optimiser since it has not been defined as an argument in the function. Any ideas how to implement it? Below is my code:

```
steps = 1000
periods = 10
steps_per_period = steps / periods

my_optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
my_optimiser = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimiser, 5.0)
dnn_classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns = construct_feature_columns(training_features),
        n_classes = 2,
        hidden_units = hidden_units,
        optimizer = my_optimiser)

training_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(
  training_features, 
  training_targets, 
  batch_size = batch_size)
predict_training_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(
  training_features, 
  training_targets, 
  num_epochs = 1, 
  shuffle = False)
predict_validation_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(
  validation_features, 
  validation_targets, 
  num_epochs = 1, 
  shuffle = False)

training_log_losses = []
validation_log_losses = []

for period in range (0, periods):

    dnn_classifier.train(
            input_fn = training_input_fn,
            steps = steps_per_period
            )
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to add regularization to your loss, and not your optimizer?
As I read in the DNNClassifier docs, it seems that this one defaults to a simple Softmax loss, and does not support the direct specification of your own loss.

Comment: Yes, I would like to specify a new loss function, but the implementation is something that I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: As I mentioned, the DNNClassifier does not allow for a custom loss. So, simply put, it doesn't work.
You would have to create your own network manually, and then choose a custom Loss function based on that.

Comment: Ok, I see. Any recommendations to replace Adam optimiser for DNN problems? My model takes approximately 10 input features and outputs binary classification (based on the labels). The number of hidden layers and the number of neurons in them is still under construction.  I have tried ProximalAdagrad and ProximalGradientDescent optimisers which let you specify L1 and L2 regularisation terms.